# Do not know how to handle this shortcode

Tags: wordpress, formbuilder

I have a form for people to sign up through our website.
https://community.leaderless.co/
This is the shortcode [civicrm component="afform" name="afformNewIndividual" hijack="0"]

With the error message:
"Do not know how to handle this shortcode."

Is there something I am overlooking.

Comment: Does the form has enough permission?

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, what is the permission it is meant to have for logged out users please?

Comment: Looks like it should be this one @PradeepNayak.
CiviCRM: add contacts
Create a new contact record in CiviCRM
?

Comment: Can't you over-ride the permission in form builder?